# Collate a list of tuples into a dictionary of tuples of lists, where the length of the tuples is unknown?

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, defaultdict

```
[('a',), ('b',), ('a',)]
```

**produces**

```
{'a': (), 'b': ()})
```

---

```
[('a', 1.0), ('b', 2.0), ('a', 3.0)]
```

**produces**

```
{'a': ([1.0, 3.0],), 'b': ([2.0],)}
```

---

```
[('a', 1.0, 0.1), ('b', 2.0, 0.2), ('a', 1.0, 0.3)]
```

**produces**

```
{'a': ([1.0, 1.0], [0.1, 0.3]), 'b': ([2.0], [0.2])}
```

---

```
[('a', 1.0, 0.1, 7), ('b', 2.0, 0.2, 8), ('a', 1.0, 0.3, 9)]
```

**produces**

```
{'a': ([1.0, 1.0], [0.1, 0.3], [7, 9]), 'b': ([2.0], [0.2], [8])}
```

I am new to Python - this is what I came up with.

```
def Collate(list_of_tuples):
    if len(list_of_tuples)==0 or len(list_of_tuples[0])==0:
        return defaultdict(tuple)
    d = defaultdict(lambda: tuple([] for i in range(len(list_of_tuples[0])-1)))
    for t in list_of_tuples:
        d[t[0]] 
        for i,v in enumerate(t):
            if i>0:
                d[t[0]][i-1].append(v)
    return d
```

In case you want to know my context, the list of tuples represents measurements. The first item in each tuple is an identification of a thing being measured.
Subsequent items are different types of measurements of that thing. The things are measured in random order, each an unknown number of times.
The function collates each things measurements together for further processing.
As the application evolves, different types of measurements will be added.
When the number of types of measurements in the client code changes, I want this Collate function to not have to change.

Comment: What should be result if tuples for the same ID contain different number of measurements, e.g. what should [('a', 1.0, 0.1), ('b', 2.0, 0.2), ('a', 3.0), ('a', 4.0, 0.4)] produce?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to *group* items first using the letters, and then collect all measurements belonging to the same id using `zip(*...)` before adding them to the corresponding dictionary key:

```
from itertools import groupby, islice
import operator

def collate(lst, f=operator.itemgetter(0)):
    d = {}
    for k, g in groupby(sorted(lst, key=f), f):
        d[k] = ()
        for v in islice(zip(*g), 1, None):
            d[k] += (list(v),)
    return d
```

---

**Tests**:

```
lst = [('a',), ('b',), ('a',)]  
print(collate(lst))
# {'a': (), 'b': ()}

lst = [('a', 1.0), ('b', 2.0), ('a', 3.0)] 
print(collate(lst))
# {'a': ([1.0, 3.0],), 'b': ([2.0],)}

lst = [('a', 1.0, 0.1, 7), ('b', 2.0, 0.2, 8), ('a', 1.0, 0.3, 9)]  
print(collate(lst))
# {'a': ([1.0, 1.0], [0.1, 0.3], [7, 9]), 'b': ([2.0], [0.2], [8])}
```

I have avoided using `defaultdict` since in the case of zero measurements (i.e. `[('a',), ('b',), ('a',)]`) you still need to explicitly set the key value; which defeats the purpose of that collection.

In case you need to handle missing measurements, replace `zip` with [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), and pass an explicit `fillvalue` to replace the default `None`.